# How to compare two multivariate distribution (of distances) to zero in terms of mean and variance in R?

Tags: r, variance, multivariate-analysis, bias, distance

We have N 3D coordinates estimated with two methods and want to compare them with a reference set of N 3D coordinates which is the ground truth, so in notations:

```
samples_method1 = [[x1_M1, y1_M1, z1_M1], [x2_M1, y2_M1, z2_M1], ..., [xN_M1, yN_M1, zN_M1] ]
samples_method2 = [[x1_M2, y1_M2, z1_M2], [x2_M2, y2_M2, z2_M2], ..., [xN_M2, yN_M2, zN_M2] ]
samples_groundtruth = [[x1_GT, y1_GT, z1_GT], [x2_GT, y2_GT, z2_GT], ..., [xN_GT, yN_GT, zN_GT] ]
```

Our idea is to:

1. Compute the 3D difference between each method and the ground truth:

```
diff_method1 = [[x1_GT- x1_M1, y1_GT- y1_M1, z1_GT- z1_M1], ..., [xN_GT- xN_M1, yN_GT- yN_M1, zN_GT- zN_M1]]
diff_method2 = [[x1_GT- x1_M1, y1_GT- y1_M2, z1_GT- z1_M2], ..., [xN_GT- xN_M2, yN_GT- yN_M2, zN_GT- zN_M2]]
```

and then evaluate which of the resulting distribution is closer to 0.

Is this a good approach ? If yes how would we quantify in R which one is closer to 0 and test it statistically (not sure if the distribution is normal so non-parametric test [incl. bootstrapping] may be useful) ?

2. How would we assess in R if the variances of the distances with the reference coordinates (i.e. the variance of `diff_method1` and `diff_method2`) are different for the two methods (ideally quantifying the variances and quantifying their differences) ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On what basis do you wish to compare them?  In terms of individual coordinates, of some kind of distance, their moments of inertia, ... ?

Comment: We would like to compare them according to the two bullet points mentioned: which one is closer to "0" and what is the amount of bias compared to 0 for each, and which one has more variance (equivalent to which of diff_method1 and diff_method2 has more variance) and what is the variance amount

Comment: "Closer" in what metric?  Several would be natural in this context, especially in light of your concern about variance.

Comment: After looking around, i'm thinking that MANOVA is not adapted since we want to compare variance to start with and one of its assumptions is variance homogeneity. So i'm looking into non parametric test which also take into account that the data is paired or in other terms repeated measures with a single within-subject factor (and not just comparing distributions since we lose information). Closer would be Euclidian distance since we are talking about spatial coordinates.

Comment: Well the distance could be the variance itself :) but i'm not sure of the most typical approach including both quantification and statistical significance. For the latter there is the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test.

Comment: The variance consists of six separate properties: all three coordinate variances and their covariances.  The K-S test is not even remotely related to this question, which makes me wonder what you're trying to ask.  The underlying problem is that the two estimation procedures are not easily compared: one might be more accurate in some dimensions and the other might be more accurate in others.  That's why you need to consider what it is you really want to compare.

Comment: The K-S test is related to this question as it would provide a significance test to know if the two distributions diff_method1 and diff_method1 are different

Comment: The test on variance difference is not necessarily based on the covariance matrix, e.g. one approach compute the euclidian distances from the N-dimensional points of a group to their centroid and then carries an F-test on the resulting group sets of distances.

Comment: I'd like to compare the means of the two distributions (more precisely samples) `diff_method1` and `diff_method1`: are they significantly different from 0 ? If yes what is the bias (i.e. mean vector). I'd also like to compare their variance: are they significantly different ? This bias/variance analysis is in the same spirit of analyzing the accuracy and precision of each method.

Answer (score 0):

Since i didn't get any answer, I thought i would answer the question myself.

1. I may be biased (this is the answer to my own question) but I think yes this is a good approach.

The distance from 0 could be quantified e.g. with the mean absolute error to avoid giving too much weight to outliers with metrics such as the mean squared error.

A non-parametric significant test to test if the distribution is significantly different from 0 can be implemented in R e.g. with the `sr.loc.test` function of the `SpatialNP` package.

2. The variance of each sample can be quantified by looking at the radial distance from their centroids. To look if they are significantly different, one can do a non-parametric test of homogeneity of multivariate dispersion as implemented in the `vegan` package.

- First a distance matrix, also called a dissimilarity matrix, can be calculated with the Euclidian distance as metric with the function `vegdist`
- Second the multivariate dispersions can be computed with `betadisper`
- Third a pairwise permutation test can be carried out with the function `permutest`, which outcome indicates if the test is significant or not

Comment: Re "this is a good approach:" your question doesn't contain enough information even to know what this "approach" is!

Comment: Whether the question contains enough information or not for the good approach, it certainly contained enough information to answer what approaches could be used to quantify the distance from 0, to test in a non-parametric way if the distribution is different from 0 and to test if the in a non-parametric way if variances of two samples are different

Comment: The basic problem is that any reasonable test of "different from 0" is utterly trivial: as soon as you observe a nonzero distance, you can conclude with certainty that the distribution differs from 0.  What is missing here is a clear statement of what you really mean by "different from 0."  I tried to elicit that from you in comments to the question.